# How to make scope functions available to compiled template in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I am trying to write a service, which will compile HTML for a directive and append it to the body element. While the text is being processed by the directive the functions are not.

Here's a simpler version which I am not able to do the same with `ng-click` directive and compiling it from the controller. Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this. My goal is to create a very basic directive similar in functionality to that of modals from angular ui-bootstrap or dialog service from Angular material.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope, $compile) {
  var html = '',
    newScope = $scope.$new(true),
    newScope1 = $scope.$new(true);

  $scope.text = 'from controller';
  $scope.fun = function() {
    alert('from controller');
  };
  newScope.text = 'from controller with new scope';
  newScope.fun = function() {
    alert('from controller with new scope');
  };
  newScope1.text = 'from controller with new scope1';
  newScope1.fun = function() {
    alert('from controller with new scope1');
  };

  html = $compile('<button ng-click="fun">{{text}}</button>')($scope);
  angular.element('body').append(html);

  html = $compile('<button ng-click="fun">{{text}}</button>')(newScope);
  angular.element('body').append(html);

  $compile('<button ng-click="fun">{{text}}</button>')(newScope1, function(clonedElement, scope) {
    console.log(clonedElement, scope);
    angular.element('body').append(clonedElement);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SNh3TudoGomwYdEv3oV1?p=preview)

Comment: why compile a directive and append it to the body instead of using a tag like `<my-directive></my-directive>` ??

Comment: When you want to open a dialog or something, may be after return of an ajax response. This approach seem to be cleaner instead of having a directive sit on the page all the time waiting for ngIf/ngShow, specially when there could be a lot of ajax or similar dialog-triggering-work going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing it right just call the method use `ng-click="fun()"` instead of `ng-click="fun"`(the only thing missing)

```
html = $compile('<button ng-click="fun()">{{text}}</button>')(newScope);
```